# How to avoid selecting columns where all their rows show the same value (SQL query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So let's say I have a Database called xjet and a table called samples where I have 3 samples with the colums: Id, Frequency and Temperature. It looks like this:

Id=1, Frequency=10000, Temperature=50

Id=2, Frequency=10000, Temperature=30

Id=3, Frequency=10000, Temperature=50

I want to not have columns shown where their value is always the same, so in this case I want the query to show:

Id=1, Temperature=50

Id=2, Temperature=30

Id=3, Temperature=50

Presuming of course that I don't know the values of temperature and frequency ahead. How can I do such a query?
I'm using MySqli and PHP if it's relevant

Comment: will frequency always been constant?  if so then just exclude it from the query

Comment: the db's job is to give you the fields you requested. it's not its job to decide "hey, this field is just repeats, I'm going to skip it". YOU determine which fields are all the same, and then simply don't request them. Which means you have to run the query twice. once to look for dupes, and another one to eliminate the dupes.

Comment: you can simply exclude it from your selection,      
but if you want to select but unique then you can use DISTINCT

Comment: QuinnFTW - No,  frequency will not always be constant. But the user can search the database based on temperature, and if he gets results where frequency happens to be the same in this temperature throughout I just don't want it to be shown.

Marc B-- You're saying SQL alone can't do it even with mutiple queries?

Comment: sany2k8-- you don't know the data ahead of time, so you wouldn't know what to exclude. DISTINCT doesn't exclude columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sitting at a LAMP setup but here is how you would write something like this.
(using ms sql2008) its very similar to mysql command.  What makes your query a bit vague is, are you going to pass frequency ? The reason when you don't display the frequency how is something/someone going to know the grouping of the values for frequency?

Create the test table and load values:

```
create table #testTable
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  Frequency int default null,
  Temperature decimal default null
)

INSERT into #testTable (Frequency, Temperature)
    VALUES
      (10000, 50),
      (10000, 30),
      (10000, 50)
      ;

declare @someValue int = 10000;

select
  tt.id,
  tt.Temperature
from
  #testTable tt
where
  tt.Frequency = @someValue
```

The code above works for only one value.

Now you said you don't know the frequency before hand the code below will produce the results for you given you don't provide a frequency. The problem with code below is you can see via the output how the rows are grouped. (The code below just uses the table from above.)

```
select 
  z.id,
  z.Temperature
from
  (
    select distinct frequency from #testTable tt group by tt.Frequency
  ) as t
inner join #testTable z on t.Frequency = z.Frequency;
```

Comment: Well, the thing is you're still manually selecting id and temperature. But what if temperature is the same and only frequency changes? Let's say you do a search based on a new column called "size" and you get that frequency changes and the temperature is the same....

Basically it appears you can't really query something like that, it needs to go through a general scripting language

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved it by employing PHP...thank you everyone for the responses

Comment: This is probably the right way to do it, as it sounds like a presentation problem, not a query problem.